# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using UIDocumentInteractionController to sent Image to Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uidocumentinteraction

I'm using this code to send and image (and eventually caption) to instagram:

```
@IBAction func sendToInstragramPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

  var image = imagePreview.image
  var imagePath = NSString(format: "%@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)][0])

  var img: String = imagePath
  var clean: String = img.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
  "[\\(\\ \\\"\\)]",
  withString: "",
  options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
  clean = clean.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
  clean = clean + "/image.igo"
  imagePath = clean

  println("test2 \(imagePath)")

  NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(imagePath, error: nil)
  UIImagePNGRepresentation(image).writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)

  var docController: UIDocumentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(imagePath)!)
  docController.delegate = self

  /*var annotationDict: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
  annotationDict["Instagram Caption"] = "Instagram Caption"
  docController.annotation = annotationDict*/

  docController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
  docController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true)
}
```

It shows me the instagram icon to touch. When I touch it, I keep getting the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at the AppDelegate but I cannot for the life of me figure out what exactly is causing this. I've done the exact same implementation in objective-c, without issue. What could be going wrong?

**EDIT**

this was happening before I manipulated the imagePath as well with this code block:

```
var img: String = imagePath
var clean: String = img.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
  "[\\(\\ \\\"\\)]",
  withString: "",
  options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
clean = clean.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
clean = clean + "/image.igo"
imagePath = clean
```

Comment: What line is the error on? What does the debugger tell you? It should jump into lldb right?

Comment: it shows on the `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` of my AppDelegate.swift file

Comment: `NSURL.fileURLWithPath(imagePath)!` is that nil? Why are you using `!` there? That doesn't seem safe.

Comment: Without it i get `Value of option type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use "i" or "?"?`

Comment: I just meant check it for nil before you go and assume `!` is going to be OK, otherwise you're going to get the run time crash you're seeing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! So it looks as though I was instantiating `UIDocumentInteractionController` in the method, So it was being trashed by ARC. Made it a class wide variable, and worked a charm

So be sure to instantiate it in the class, and then reference it in the method

ie:

`var docController: UIDocumentInteractionController!`

Comment: You don't need to add a `!` in a variable declaration, if you don't have a `?` it's by default considered not nil.

Comment: when i take out the `!` i get an error - saying "class '...' has no initializers. what is going on?

Comment: Really? I may be mistaken, I'll have to read more about it, sorry for the bad advice.